# Python SocketServer.UDPServer for file downloading

Tags: python, tcp, udp, webserver

I am trying to make a UDP server, on a VM, for the purpose of downloading files off of the VM from a separate or host computer. I've been doing reading and research, but have yet to find something that can completely serve my purpose.

If this has already been discussed or answered, I would appreciate the link, as I could not find this answered.

I'm using this simple python code that was found online and may seem the norm to some.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
PORT = 8000
Handler = SimpleHTTPSServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("",PORT),Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is what I found online, and it works perfectly for what I'm currently needing, EXCEPT.. I need it to be UDP, not TCP. When I pop open a Wireshark, I can see the traffic coming through as TCP.

I did find something where the following line ...

```
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("",PORT),Handler)
```

was changed to ..

```
httpd = SocketServer.UDPServer(("",PORT),Handler)
```

Now, I made this change. The code still runs without a problem. Then when I attempt to perform a download as normal as..

```
https://<IPADDRESS>:8000/<FILENAME>.<FILEEXTENSION>
```

Where this would have started the download on the TCPServer, I now receive an "Unable to Connect" message from both FireFox and Chrome, on the UDPServer.

Can someone explain why this is so? Or point out where I messed up, in order to make this work as a UDPServer, broadcasting openly on the network, upon the HTTP Request?

If this isn't possible, and I need to start from scratch, let me know.

Again, I apologize if this has already been addressed. I would appreciate the links to the thread.

Comment: HTTP is a TCP protocol. It does not work on UDP.

Comment: Well, bananas... I appreciate the info.

Comment: I guess I'll have to write up a HTTP request through TCP to initiate a UDP broadcast? Then set up a UDP Capture/Catcher?